# Cypress cucumber tests not working in GitHub Actions

Tags: cucumber, cypress, github-actions

All the tests run successfully locally with the command `npx cypress run`. But the same tests fail in GitHub Actions with this error:

> AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms

Appreciate your help. Please find the workflows yml file below:

```yaml
name: E2e Tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.2.0
        env:
          DEBUG: "cypress:*"
        with:
          # start: npm start
          command: npx cypress run
          # command: npx cypress run --browser chrome --spec 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature'
```

Dependencies:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^17.0.0",
        "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0",
        "@cypress/xpath": "^2.0.3",
        "cypress": "^12.11.0",
        "cypress-cucumber-attach-screenshots-to-failed-steps": "^1.0.0",
        "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
        "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.4.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
        "typescript": "^4.5.2"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having this issue anymore ? Why explicitly launching with "command: npx cypress run" if you use the cypress-io/github-action@v4.2.0. In my case only put the snippet below will make it:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
    with:
      build: npm run build
      start: npm start
```